Angular fragment router with route buttons does not render component
I am trying to use the fragment routes on angular18(standalone components) for the first time. Clicking on the route links changes the routes to the fragment route, eg "/#about" but the component does not render unless I go to the normal routes eg "/about".
I have the following set up:
routes.ts:
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component'; 
export const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
    // {path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
];

header.component.html(this has the fragment links):
<div id = "header">
    <div id = "home_bttn">
        <a routerLink = "/" fragment = "">Home</a>
    </div>   
    <div id = "sections">
        <a routerLink="/" fragment= "about" >About</a>
    </div>
</div>

about.component.ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrl: './about.component.scss'
})
export class AboutComponent {
}

about.component.html:
<div id = "about">About works</div>

styles.scss:
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#main-container {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    background-color: orange;
}

app.container.html:
<div id="main-container">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
</div>


In your main component (or main module) do you have a line like this? provideRouter(appRoutes, withHashLocation())

@ChrisGilardi No I do not. I just added it, and now i get double-hashed routes like this: "/#/#about"

Now that you added that, try routing directly to the routes, instead of using fragment. Try changing your routerlink to /about directly.
